# New data is added to random position while scrolling instead of on the top of list

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

To display the list from firestore using pagination I am using the following [link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902).
Everything is the same except I am fetching data in Descending order.

Initially or while scrolling, It is fetching correct data.
When I added new data to firestore and at the same time I am scrolling then new data is added to a random position instead of on the top of the list.

How to add data at the top of the list? (Remaining code is similar to the link)

Following is my MainActivity.kt Code

```
private var query: Query = productsRef.whereEqualTo("userId", userId).orderBy("timestampAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(LIMIT.toLong())

private var productList: MutableList<UserProductModel?> = ArrayList()
 
private fun getProductList() {

        val ProductListLiveData: ProductListLiveData? = ProductListViewModel?.getProductListLiveData()
        ProductListLiveData?.observe(this) { operation ->
            if (operation != null) {
                when (operation.type) {
                    R.string.added -> {
                        val addedProductList: UserProductModel = operation.userProductModel
                        addProductList(addedProductList)
                    }
                    R.string.modified -> {
                        val modifiedProductList: UserProductModel = operation.userProductModel
                        modifyProductList(modifiedProductList)
                    }
                    R.string.removed -> {
                        val removedProductList: UserProductModel = operation.userProductModel
                        removeProductList(removedProductList)
                    }
                }
            }
 
            // Restore state
            rv_Product.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
            completeProductListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun addProductList(addedProductList: UserProductModel) {
            productList.add(addedProductList)
    }

    private fun modifyProductList(modifiedProductList: UserProductModel) {
        for (i in 0 until productList.size) {
            val currentProductList: UserProductModel? = productList[i]
            if (currentProductList != null) {
                if (currentProductList.ProductId.equals(modifiedProductList.ProductId)) {
                    productList.remove(currentProductList)
                    productList.add(i, modifiedProductList)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun removeProductList(removedProductList: UserProductModel) {
        for (i in 0 until productList.size) {
            val currentProductList: UserProductModel? = productList[i]
            if (currentProductList != null) {
                if (currentProductList.ProductId.equals(removedProductList.ProductId)) {
                    productList.remove(currentProductList)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerViewOnScrollListener() {
        val onScrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener = object :
            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true
                }
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?
                if (layoutManager != null) {
                    val firstVisibleProductPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                    val visibleProductCount = layoutManager.childCount
                    val totalProductCount = layoutManager.itemCount
                    if (isScrolling && firstVisibleProductPosition + visibleProductCount == totalProductCount) {
                        isScrolling = false
                        getProductList()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        rv_Product.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, here is a official documentation about pagination data from firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#kotlin+ktx

Comment: I got it but in my case, 2 events are happening at the same time 1:- new data added 2:- scrolling at the same time.  This means in both cases data is loading at the same time. That's why it is adding it at random places.  How to solve that